# x axis date and time shows 01/01/1970 01:00:00 instead of current time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqtgraph

In my project with raspberry pi and pyqtgraph. I am trying to plot system time on x axis which works great on windows but not on raspbian. Instead of showing system time and date it starts updating x axis from 01/01/1970 01:00:00. I am confused how to proceed. heres my code

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph.exporters
import time

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')


win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Live Graphs")  # creating a window for graphs
win.resize(1920, 720)
win.setWindowTitle('Condition Monitoring')   # Setting up the title
win.ci.setBorder((50, 50, 100))

class CAxisTime(pg.AxisItem):
    ## Formats axis label to human readable time.
    # @param[in] values List of \c time_t.
    # @param[in] scale Not used.
    # @param[in] spacing Not used.
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        strns = []
        for x in values:
            try:
                strns.append(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y\n %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(x)))    # time_t --> time.struct_time
            except ValueError:  # Windows can't handle dates before 1970
                strns.append('')
        return strns

axis1 = CAxisTime(orientation='bottom')

p1 = win.addPlot(axisItems={'bottom': axis1}, title = '<b>Humidity')  # creating the plot for humidity
curve1 = p1.plot(pen = '#00A3E0')  # setting up the curve and the color
humC1 = [] # an empty list for humidity values
times1 = [] # an empty time list 
indx1 = 0   # variable set to zero
hum = BrickletHumidity(UIDhum, ipcon) # Humidity Bricklet 

def updateSensorHum():
    global curve1,tempC1, indx1, times1, hum, t0

    humidity = hum.get_humidity() # get the value of the relative humidity from humidity bricklet 

    dataArray1=str(humidity/10).split(',')  # creating a data array and splitting the values  
    temp1 = float(dataArray1[0]) # creating a float object of data array
    humC1.append(temp1) # appending the humidity values
    times1.append(time.time())   # appending the time values

    if (indx1 > 250):  # if indx1 > 300
        humC1.pop(0)    # start eliminating the 1st value stored in the array
        times1.pop(0) # start eliminating the time from the x axis
    indx1 = indx1 + 1   # increase index by 1
    curve1.setData(humC1) # drawing the curve humidity vs time
    app.processEvents() #process the events in the created app

def update():
    updateSensorHum() # update Humidity Sensor

    exporter = pg.exporters.ImageExporter(win.scene()) # export the image exporter library
    exporter.export('ConditionMonitoring.png') # export the file as SVG

timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer() # import timer library
timer.timeout.connect(update) # set the connection with the function to be update
timer.start(999) # start the timer
```

I'd be thankful if someone can help me with this as this problem is bothering me since two days without any solution

Kind regards,
Ajay

Comment: Does your raspberry pi have a correct system time? 1970/1/1 00:00.00 UTC is [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).The raspberry pi does not have a battery backed RTC so the system time resets to epoch on every power-up until it connects to the internet and syncs time via NTP (if set up). You can check by using the `date` command in terminal.

Comment: @ca508 thanks for replying. yes Rpi has correct time. It's just weird that the script works on windows and not on rpi. Also when I remove `time.localtime(x)` I get the real time but on x axis I get all messed up similar values. I tried printing `strns=[ ]` it prints the same time in the whole array instead of appending it to the new values. For example at an instance of 19:24:23 the whole array will be [19:24:23 19:24:23 19:24:23 19:24:23] and the next second [19:24:24 19:24:24 19:24:24 19:24:24].. It's really weird and difficult to explain.